# How to customize the message "Changes you made may not be saved." for window.onbeforeunload?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am testing in Google Chrome.

I did some search and found that someone is using:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (hook) {
      return "Did you save your stuff?"
    }
  }
```

But when I use it, I still got the "Changes you made may not be saved." message. How can I change it to something I want?

Comment: This may be a duplicate, but before the June 2, 2016 release, it was possible to have a custom message in the Google Chrome beforeunload event.  All of the other questions related to this should include that information.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can't, the ability to do this was removed in Chrome 51. It is widely considered a security issue, and most vendors have removed support.

> ### [Custom messages in onbeforeunload dialogs (removed)](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5349061406228480):
>
> A window’s onbeforeunload property may be set to a function that returns a string. If the function returns a string, then before unloading the page, a dialog is shown to have the user confirm that they indeed want to navigate away. The string provided by the function will no longer be shown in the dialog. Rather, a generic string not under the control of the webpage will be shown.
>
> #### Comments
>
> This shipped in Safari 9.1, and has been shipping in Firefox since Firefox 4. Safari considers this a security fix and assigned it CVE-2009-2197 (see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206171 ). Approved with the intent https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/blink-dev/YIH8CoYVGSg/Di7TsljXDQAJ .
>
> #### Specification
>
> [Established standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#unloading-documents)
>
> #### Status in Chromium
>
> Removed ([launch bug](http://crbug.com/587940)) in:
>
> - Chrome for desktop release 51
> - Chrome for Android release 51
> - Android WebView release 51
> - Opera release 38
> - Opera for Android release 38

Comment: Just wondering, if there's no way to customize it, can I simply use:

`window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {};` and `window.onbeforeunload = null;` to activate/deactivate it?

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo Yes, you can still disable it by removing your previous event handlers.

Comment: You can use window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {} and disable the pop-up in the same time. Just return null at the end of the function: window.onbeforeunload = somefunc; function somefunc() { /*do sth*/ return null;}

Answer (score 0):

In my Vue 2 application, I was able to use: `window.onbeforeunload = null;` in `mounted()` and popup does not open after submitting a form.