# Customized Chrome prompt box's warning word and listened the confirm & cancel btn

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    window.event.returnValue = "真的要刷新页面么？";
    return '2222';
});
```

How to self-customized the  prompt box warning words when closing or updating an unsaved  page in Chrome , and listen the confirm or cancal button click event ?

Comment: by _google browser_ you mean chrome?

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: i mean how to self-customized the  prompt box warning words when closing or updating an unsaved  page in Chrome , and listen the confirm or cancal button click event ?

Comment: yes,i mean chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize the message "Changes you made may not be saved." for window.onbeforeunload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40570164/how-to-customize-the-message-changes-you-made-may-not-be-saved-for-window-onb)

Answer (score 0):

The `beforeunload` dialog bog isn't customizable. Any value other than the empty string indicates a request to confirm unloading the document, but the value itself isn't used for anything.

You can use `e.preventDefault()` instead if you like.

Reference: [§ 7.8.11.1 The BeforeUnloadEvent interface](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#the-beforeunloadevent-interface)

This changed in Chrome 51, Firefox 44, and Safari 9.1 (see [2](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5349061406228480)).