# Angular - Override default browser message when leaving the browser without saving changes

Tags: angular, browser

In my angular application I want to display a message when the user tries to reload or leave the browser without saving his changes or when a background process is still running (according to a flag in my code).

However, The only option I found is to enable the default browser alert, with its default message: *"Changes you made may not be saved."*

I cannot find any way to override this popup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize the message "Changes you made may not be saved." for window.onbeforeunload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40570164/how-to-customize-the-message-changes-you-made-may-not-be-saved-for-window-onb)

Answer (score 0):

you can try bellow code:

```
@Component({ 
  selector: 'app-root',
  ..
)}
class AppComponent{
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  doSomething($event) {
    if(this.hasChanges) $event.returnValue='Your data will be lost!';
  }
```